# clicking on element gives 2 diffrent type of button how to check if one of them exists

Tags: javascript, promise

When I click on `button a` after 1 second I might get `button b` or after 6 sec I might get `button c`

So, let's say using this function we can wait for the element until this element appear inside the page.

```
const checkElement = async selector => {
  while ( document.querySelector(selector) === null) {
    await new Promise( resolve =>  requestAnimationFrame(resolve) )
  }
  return document.querySelector(selector); 
};
```

And then we use it like this:

```
checkElement('.myElement').then((selector) => {
  console.log(selector);
});
```

But how to know which one gonna appear to use promise to not waste time and CPU.

Comment: Can you explain why you have while ( document.querySelector(selector) === null) {

Comment: like that i am saying to my code while queryselector can not find the selector wait for new promise to resolve so it checks and check and when find then it gives it to me..this function works for when waiting for one single item but i realy can not understand how to make it work in multiple now after many search i find there is await promise.all which i want to try at the moment